# jQuery change look af an active element?

Tags: jquery, hover, click

I have ajax menu and I want to change the look of currently selected item. How to do that if the item is not a "real" link with href and just shows hidden div?

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FXua/

When user clicks "Link #1" I want the text "Link #1" to be white and link's background to be black. When user clicks "Link #2" i want the text "Link #2" to be white (...).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/9FXua/1/

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var divID = $('#'+id.substring(0,id.indexOf('-')));
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $(divID).show();       
});
```

with a new css class `active`

```
ul li a.active { background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

in the click handler.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9FXua/2/).